# Simple mod_rewrite, replace one word in every instance

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I've been looking for an answer to this forever and can't find it, yet it seems like it should be so simple!

I want to use mod_rewrite to replace a word in a url in every instance that it shows up, but I don't want a redirect to happen, just changing the way the url appears to site users.

Example:

Change

```
mysite.com/something/groups/anything...
```

to:

```
mysite.com/something/projects/anything...
```

I know I could go through and start tweaking files but mod_rewrite would work much better because I'm sure I'll mess something up otherwise (for reference I'm using `joomla/jomsocial`).

Comment: Changing the way the URL appears to site users is possible only through a redirect.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule something/groups/.*$ something/projects/$1
```